# Don't understand this coding - list pointers

Tags: arrays, pointers, singly-linked-list

I am experiencing some great difficulty on this.

How would the singly linked list look like for an array [6, 10, 15, 24]? What does p.next refer to?

```
p.next = p.next.next;
p.next = new Node(19, p.next);
p.next.next = new Node(28);
p.next.next = p;
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain to me what is going on. I have been trying so hard to work it out, and it has been greatly bothering me.

Comment: is this c++? you need to tag the language

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a Node has a value and points to a new Node.

If the constructor for a Node is Node(value, nextNode), here would be some code to make a list that converts that array to a NodeList.

```
int[] arr = {6, 10, 15, 24};
Node currentNode = null;
for(int x = arr.length - 1; x >= 0; x--)
currentNode = new Node(arr[x], currentNode);
```

This is a bit complex, but I'll try and explain it. You have your array and a Node which is null. You then traverse the array backwards. You create a new Node which has the value of the last index of the array and points to null. You then move down the array and have a new node that points to the last node you created. Hopefully this makes sense. Feel free to comment with questions.

And `.next` points to the next node in the list.

EDIT: Everything below

Notation I'll use for a Node: `[val]->nodePointingTo`

The list, when complete, would look like this.

`[6] -> [10] -> [15] -> [24] -> null`
In a linear NodeList, null has to be used at the end because it's the only way to show there's an end.

This is what's happening throughout that for loop.

Value of currentNode: `null`.
Value of currentNode: `[24] -> null`
value of currentNode: `[15] -> [24]` //I'll only point to currentNode's next node
Value of currentNode: `[10] -> [15]`
Value of currentNode: `[6] -> [10]`
The end.
The final output will have 6, which is pointing to a node which has a value of 10. That node is pointing to a node with a value of 15. That node is pointing to a node with a value of 24. And THAT node is pointing to `null`, because there's nothing else for it to point to. 
I hope this cleared things up.

Comment: Sorry, could you draw it please? I don't get any of it :(

Comment: @user3138212 I updated my response. Hopefully it makes a bit more sense now.

Comment: Also, the reason you can chain `.next` is because `.next` points to another node. So if you say `head` is the node with the value of 6, `head.next` points to the node with a value of 10 and `head.next.next` points to the node with a value of 10, and then to its next node, which has the value of 15.